# Kendo Grid Command.Edit() Not firing to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Problem: When clicking on Update Button it does not call the controller Action. But the same work perfectly fine for Create/Read/Destroy. Anything that i am missing???? Please let me know.

View Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
       .Name("XGrid")
       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 525px;" })
       .Columns(columns =>
       {
           //Columns...

       })
       .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
       .ToolBar(toolbar =>
       {               
               toolbar.Create();               
       })
       .Pageable()
       .Sortable()
       .Scrollable()
       .Filterable()
       .Events(events =>
       {
           events.Edit("onEdit");
           events.Save("onSave");
       })
       .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           .Ajax()
           .PageSize(12)
           .ServerOperation(true)
           .Model(model =>
           {
               model.Id(ex => ex.User_ID);                   
           })
           .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateUser", "ViewUser"))
           .Read(read => read.Action("UsersRetreive", "ViewUser"))
           .Create(create => create.Action("CreateUser", "ViewUser"))
       )
    )
```

Controller Code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateUser([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Login objUpdate)
    {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Saving Code                                      
            }
            else
                return Json(objUpdate);
        }
```

Comment: Is it not hitting the action method at all or not returning a result?

Comment: its not hitting the action at all...:(

Comment: Thx for responding @mmillican any idea what could be the problem????

Comment: Are there any requests in the network tab of the browser, if yes what did the server say? Also how did you define the  edit button command? Are you sure that you added the aspnetmvc script as needed?

Comment: Hi Petur.. Thx for responding.. 
No...
Command(command => { command.Edit(); });
Yes. Otherwise how would Create and Destroy would work??? Also there are other screen but with diff variation of edit which is working. In this scenario, when i click on update nothing happens and it ll be in the edit mode.. no error shown in the browser console as well and no redirection.

Comment: you are missing "toolbar.Save()", add it and it will hit your controller method

Answer (score 2):

For **GridEditMode**.Inline, you have to use `toolbar.Save()` to save the data and hit the controller

Answer (score 1):

Sure, It will not hit until you change event a one letter of any inline cell. It means if you not do modification it will not hit the action.

Comment: Thank you for saving me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `HttpPost` attribute to the action method, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUser([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Login objUpdate)
{
}
```

Kendo is sending a `POST` and that current method is only accepting `GET` requests.

Also, make sure that the method is returning:

```
return Json(objUpdate.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```

Comment: i had already tried that but no luck :( Actually i had forgot to mention [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] in the controller method...Have modified the code..

Comment: Is the `Login` param you're passing in the same as the others?  It looks like it should work, but I added another thing to check to the answer above.